# How does Webpack resolve entry module names such as 'jquery' & '@angular/xxx'

Tags: webpack

The documentation for webpack entry points (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) says that the entry value should point to a file.

```
const config = {
  entry: {
    main: './path/to/my/entry/file.js'
  }
};
```

However, in many of the examples I've seen (usually surrounding creating a vendor specific output) I have noticed that a list of modules is given instead.

```
var config = {
  // ...
  entry: {
      vendors: ['@angular/core','react','jquery']
  }
  // ...
}
```

How is Webpack taking the strings '@angular/core', or 'jquery' for instance, and resolving those to javascript source files on disk? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default webpack follows the module resolution of Node.js. When the import is neither an absolute path (starting with `/`) nor explicitly a relative path (starting with `./` or `../`), it is resolved as a module, which means that it's [Loading from `node_modules` Folders](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

For instance if you import `jquery` you will use the module installed from npm, which should be in `./node_modules/jquery`. If the module is not found in that directory, it moves to the parent directory and checks its `node_modules` directory. And so on until the module was found or the root of the file system is reached.

Webpack allows you to change where to look for modules, by configuring [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules). If you configure that option, you should make to sure to include `"node_modules"` as well, otherwise you won't be able to import modules installed from npm.